# delayed job worker quits when database unavailable

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I use delayed job with the ActiveRecord backend using mysql on a distributed system. Whenever I restart the mysql database, the workers simply stop. According to the log, each worker attempts to reconnect 8 times with 5 second intervals and then quits with a `FATAL -- : MySQL client is not connected` message.

This means that each time I restart the database, I have to also restart all my workers.

Is there a way to increase the number of reconnection attempts?

Answer (score 0):

In the job:

`class MyJob < ActiveJob::Base
  retry_on(YourMySQLException, wait: 10.seconds, attempts: 10)
end`

If you want this retrying behaviour to be the default for all your jobs, consider putting this line in `ApplicationJob`, and have all your jobs inherit from it.

The official documentation has different defaults than the ones you inferred from the logs, but I guess it doesn't matter => https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Exceptions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-retry_on

Nevertheless, another question might be: why do you need to restart mysql? This should probably not happen in a production environment...

Comment: I already checked those docs, but figured this was related to the number of times an actual job gets retried if it fails for some reason. In my case, it's the worker checking the database if there are any new jobs. Restarting mysql is not something we do actively pursue, but this can always happen. If it happens, everything resumes after the issue, except the workers, those processes are just stopped.

Comment: @bmesuere Did u find any solution to this issue? Even I'm facing a similar issue. The worker stops and Delayed Job never tries to establish a new connection.

Comment: @gsk no, we added additional monitoring and alerts